# VBA Code taking forever to run - where can I optimize it?

Tags: excel, vba

My code works perfectly in the original spreadsheet that I have been working on. I now pasted it into a different sheet and I pasted it elsewhere , and now it has been laggy af. It takes forever to run the code below. I removed the select functions because I heard that could cause it to run slow. What else can I do? I am handling large amounts of data (65000  rows) so ..... any tips?

```
Sub RealMonthlyActivityThirdBusinessDay()

    Dim FeeReport As Variant
    Dim FeeReportWB As Workbook
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, MasterList As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Improves Performance
    FeeReport = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select your Fee Report", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    If FeeReport <> False Then Set FeeReportWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(FeeReport) Else Exit Sub
    
    Dim TotalSheets As Long
    TotalSheets = FeeReportWB.Sheets.Count

    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Fee Information")

    For i = 1 To TotalSheets
        Set ws = FeeReportWB.Worksheets(i)
        ws.Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ws.Columns("C:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ws.Columns("H:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ws.Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        ws.Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        ws.Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        
        'filter for Non Managed Fee Based
        
        ws.Range("G2").AutoFilter
        ws.Range("$A$2:$T$65000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
            "Non Managed Fee Based"
        'Hide the column
        ws.Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        
        'Copy the filtered workbook but have to hide rows 1 and 2 first because I am copying all visible cells
        ws.Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
        RowCount = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("A1:T65000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Cells(RowCount, "A")
        Set ws = Nothing
    Next i
    
    'Clearing Fee Charged column
    Set MasterList = Workbooks("Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Master List_March21")
    
    Dim FeeChargedItems As Long
    
    FeeChargedItems = MasterList.Cells(Rows.Count, 31).End(xlUp).Row
    MasterList.Columns(31).ClearContents
    MasterList.Range("AE1").Value = "Fee Charged"
    
    RowCountTotal = MasterList.Cells(Rows.Count, 29).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Filling the Fee Information
    MasterList.Range("AE2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Fee Information'!A:B,2,False)"
    MasterList.Activate
    MasterList.Range("AE2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE" & RowCountTotal)
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: No need to `AutoFill`: `MasterList.Range("AE2:AE" & RowCountTotal).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F2,'Fee Information'!A:B,2,False)"`.

Comment: There's a duplicate `ws.Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False`.

Comment: Avoid using `Select` and `Selection`, also using `With ws` can help you make your code shorter and clearer. Did you think using Arrays ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting "Application.Calculation= xlManual" at the start, and then setting it back to "application.calculation = xlAutomatic" at the end.

The Vlookup formula has probably a big impact on performance, and using the commands above will prevent it from calculating while you're placing it on the cells. It will calculate only once at the end of the code.